# Build own assert class

Tags: typescript, types, tdd, assert

I would like to create my own little assertion class. I tried to install mocha and chai, but got lots and lots of errors from deep within those modules, so for the moment I'd rather try something self-built, if not at least to learn more TypeScript.

I found a good template (https://gist.github.com/brunolm/6031927) of a class, and the implementations for IsFalse, IsTrue, AreEqual work just fine. I extended it for my needs with an IsNullOrUndefined, all good so far.

I would also like to use the IsInstanceOf test. It is implemented like this:

```
public static IsInstanceOfType(expectedType: Function, actual: any): void {
    if (!(actual instanceof expectedType)) {
        // some more code to construct a message, and throw
    }
}
```

I cannot get that code to work though. I do not know how / what to pass as first argument. I try like this

```
Assert.IsInstanceOfType((): List<string> => { return undefined; }, list);
```

with List<> being my own generic collection class, and list being an instance of it (or not... that's to find out).

The code above compiles, but fails the assertion fails even when it should not. I find the "pass a function that returns the type you expect" strange, and would prefer something nicer, if possible.
If this is the way to go, then I am using it wrong - how would you use it?

I asked the author, and he suggest I should call like this

```
Assert.IsInstanceOfType(List<string>, list);
```

but that does not go through with the compiler, that can't be right, or is it? I cannot get it to work - that is the type written out, not a function?!?

Any suggestion?

Comment: I switched the functions parameter order in what is shown here compared to the original linked class. This, sadly, is not already the solution to the question. The problem how to pass the parameter, not the order in which they are put...

Answer (score 0):

```
public static IsInstanceOfType(type: Function, instance: any): void {
    if (!(instance instanceof type)) {
        // some more code to construct a message, and throw
    }
}
```

then

```
const Foo = function() {};
Assert.IsInstanceOfType(Foo, new Foo()); // true
```

I hope this will direct you toward solution.

Give us code of your *List* object if you need more help.